# How many countries can I add in the setComponentRestrictions in Google Map autocomplete

Tags: dictionary, autocomplete

I am going to add a number of countries in the array of setComponentRestrictions in Google Map autocomplete, so that address in only those countries can be filtered in the autocomplete.
But I see that only first 5 countries work for this, not all the countries I added
Is there anyone can help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, Google Map Autocomplete can recognize 5 countries at maximum as a restriction